# TextArea inside padding and new Line in React Native

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-redux, textarea, react-styleguidist

i'm trying to make inside padding of textarea but can't do it. another poeblem is  inside textarea when i start writing something it always go a single long long line  doesn't make new line. Can anyone there who can help me by letting me know the two properties?
I have attached a  screenshoot left one is given design and right one is i've made.[image]

Comment: Try to Add Padding inside TextInpute

Answer (score 2):

set multilne to true

```
<TextInput multiline={true} />
```

and for padding, set `style={{padding: 10}}`, like this

```
<TextInput multiline={true} style={{padding: 10}} />
```

Also write `textAlignVertical="top"` otherwise the `placeholder` will be positioned in the center, finally write like this

```
<TextInput multiline={true} style={{padding: 10}} textAlignVertical="top" />
```

[Working Example](https://snack.expo.io/@kartikeyvaish/multiline-textinput-example)